# Date calculation issue in excel

Tags: excel, function, formula

Could you please help me in below calculations?
Problems are highlighted in red colour in the snapshot below.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put 1/Jul/21 in B1 and 1/Jul/23 in C1,

Then this:

```
YEAR(C1)-YEAR(B1)
```

gives the result 2.

Use month() etc to complete the others, as you provided an image I just did one.